# Parse docker logs with logstash

Tags: docker, logstash

I have a docker container that log to stdout/stderr. Docker save it's output into /var/lib/docker/containers//-logs.json

The log has lines with the following structure

```
{"log":"This is a message","stream":"stderr","time":"2015-03-12T19:27:27.310818102Z"}
```

which input/codec/filter should I use to get only the `log` field as the `message` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [json codec](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/codecs/json) to parse the JSON string (you could instead use the [json filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/json)), then rename the "log" field to "message" with the [mutate filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/mutate) and finally use the [date filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/date) to parse the "time" field.

```
filter {
  mutate {
    rename => ["log", "message"]
  }
  date {
    match => ["time", "ISO8601"]
    remove_field => ["time"]
  }
}
```

Comment: that's on the shipper?

Comment: Either. The json codec setting obviously needs to be connected to the input plugin for the logfile but the filters can be anywhere. I prefer centralizing all filters on the Logstash hub servers.

Comment: I think instead you would need the json_lines input method, as each line would be a seperate JSON document.